# Insert query failing with a Syntax error while trying to run it

Tags: sql, database

Movie Table has 4 Attributes: movie_id, moive_name, desc, genre_id

movie_id (autoNumber) PK

moive_name(short Text)

desc(long Text)

genre_id(number) FK

This is the query I am trying to run

`INSERT INTO Movie (moive_name,description,genre_id)
VALUES('Rise','dfdsfsa','1')`

I know moive_name is miss spelled but its like that in the db aswell will fix it later.

I am still getting a systax error
`java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.`
I am sure the table is called Movie. I left out the movie_id field since I want it to auto fill with the next number as its autoNumber. Do you guys maybe know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: '1' isn't a number, try 1

Answer (score 0):

In your table have four values , but you are trying to insert with three values.
It won't work in oracle.Create Movie_id as a primary key without auto increment and create sequence for your movie id

```
CREATE SEQUENCE movie_id
MINVALUE 1
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
CACHE 10
```

and try this insert statement

```
INSERT INTO Movie (movie_id,moive_name,description,genre_id)
VALUES(movie_id.nextval,'Rise','dfdsfsa','1')
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you are trying to insert a string in number '1' should be like 1

```
INSERT INTO Movie (moive_name,description,genre_id)
VALUES('Rise','dfdsfsa',1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Tristan,
Provide genre_id without single codes as it is a numeric value. Not sure how you are generating movie_id, if it is a sequence number, provide the number

```
INSERT INTO Movie (movie_id,moive_name,description,genre_id)
VALUES (your_movie_id,'Rise','dfdsfsa',1)
```